# Bug in TTextButtonObjectAppearance under TListview (FMX)?

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

Using `TTextButtonObjectAppearance` in TListview (FMX), there is a Width property in Object Inspector.  However, the Height property is missing.

Tracing back the code, it inherits from `TListItemDrawable` which
has both Height & Width properties - it's public fields, not published.

```
property Width: Single index 0 read FWidth write SetOneDimension;
property Height: Single index 1 read FHeight write SetOneDimension;
```

How to amend the Delphi source to let Height be published just like Width?
Otherwise, it's troublesome to have to always change the Height in the `OnUpdateObjects`
code to set height of a button.

I believe this cannot be by deliberate design to allow setting of Width but not Height.

Thanks.

Delphi 10.4.0

[image]

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using? Edit your question to add that information.

Comment: I updated qn with 10.4.0. thanks :)

Comment: There is an update to your Delphi version. You should try it. If you add a simple basic example, I will try it for you. Publish the .pas and .fmx files in your question.

Comment: @fpiette Delphi 10.4.1 did not fix the problem. I edited the post to show a screenshot of the Object Inspector.  The Height property is still missing; the Width property is there.

Answer (score 1):

It finally took Idera Delphi 11.0 to add in a Height property for TTextButtonObjectAppearance.  Issue resolved.